# Сколько входных переменных обычно используют булевы функции?

Tags: булева-алгебра

Мне нужно написать программу, минимизирующую булеву функцию. Выбрав один из самых эффективных алгоритмов, среди всех выделил 3: Квайна МакКласки, с помощью кодов Грея, а также эвристический алгоритм Эспрессо.

Вопрос про использование минимизации на практике для выбора алгоритма - **сколько входных переменных обычно используют булевы функции ?**